# Create Meta tag from reading data in URL using PHP

Tags: php, metadata, meta-tags

I need help with the following please:

I have one PHP page that reads from a database and creates 1000's of pages - too many to create meta data for each page. I need to create meta data from the info in the url:

Instance 1:
http://dom.com/page.php/area1/type1
http://dom.com/page.php/area1/type2

Instance 2:
http://dom.com/page.php/area1/type1/name
http://dom.com/page.php/area1/type2/proper%20name

Area = 1-30 (lookup from list provided)
Type = 1-2 (lookup from list provided)
Name = strip "%20" for spaces in names

Populate:
Instance 1:

```
<title>Type, Area</title>
<meta content="Type, Area" name="description"
```

Instance 2:

```
<title>Proper Name, Type, Area</title>
<meta content="Proper Name, Type, Area" name="description" />
```

Any help with be highly appreciated!

Comment: Duplicating the title in the description is worthless. You are almost certainly much better off leaving it out and letting search engines generate the description from the content.

Answer (score 1):

Carlo,
This should work (paste it where your meta tag should be):

```
<?php
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
// if url has a path (/whatever/somethingelse)
if (isset($url['path'])
  {
  // split the path on every slash
  $a_path = explode('/', $url['path']);
  // reverse the order of the parts, join them with commas and replace %20
  $info = str_replace('%20', ' ', join(', ', array_reverse($a_path)));
  // print info to page
  print '<title>' . $info . '</title>';
  print '<meta content="' . $info . '" name="description" />';
  }
?>
```

Although I agree that pasting the title in the meta description probably isn't the best idea.

Edit: follow-up on your comment:

```
// pop off the last value of the path parts
$info = str_replace('%20', ' ', array_pop($a_path));
```

Comment: Thanks Chris!! 
Is it possible to just use the first value in the reverse array and drop the rest? That will be perfect!
Many thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome. Of course, but then you would be doing something different than what you described in your initial post? I edited the answer with the code you described.